# Hadoop Client unable to connect to datanode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop3

I have  single node hadoop cluster on ec2. Tried to give all posible combinations in slaves file.

```
May 01 2020 08:16:25.227 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - pipeline = 172.31.45.114:9866 
May 01 2020 08:16:25.227 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - pipeline = 172.31.45.114:9866 
May 01 2020 08:16:25.228 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Connecting to datanode 172.31.45.114:9866 
May 01 2020 08:16:25.228 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Connecting to datanode 172.31.45.114:9866 
May 01 2020 08:16:35.167 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (2007716372) connection to ec-x.x.x.x/x.x.x.x:54310 from vgs: closed
```

I have tried to bind the datanode to external ip , but its not binding, by default its binding on internal ip of the machine.

Also used `dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname` as true, still client is receiving the internal ip not external.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run spark on EMR you need at least 2 nodes (I managed to run it on minimum 3, but from what I'm reading- I assume 2 should also be enough) - 1 node - MASTER is not enough.
You need MASTER and CORE.
Here you have some more comprehensive guide how to do it:
https://medium.com/big-data-on-amazon-elastic-mapreduce/run-a-spark-job-within-amazon-emr-in-15-minutes-68b02af1ae16